# Insert spaces to break up even sets of characters within a C++ String

Tags: c++, string, break

I am trying to write a function that will find any even subsets of characters in a string, and break them in half by inserting an empty space into the string. For example, given the string "AA BBB CCDD", my string should be converted to "A A BBB CC DD".

My breakString() function doesn't seem to work, and I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

```
void breakString(string &str1)
{
    int pos1 = -1;
    int pos2 = str1.find_first_of(" ", pos1+1);

    while (pos2 != -1)
    {
        if(((pos2-pos1)-1)%2 == 0)
        {
            str1.insert((pos2-pos1)/2, 1, ' ');
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            pos1 = pos2;
            pos2 = str1.find_first_of(' ', pos1+1);
        }
    }

    if((str1.size() - pos1)%2 == 1)     
        str1.insert((str1.length()-pos1)/2, 1, ' ');

    return;
}
```

Comment: Hello, @user, welcome to Stack Overflow! Is this a learning exercise? If so, please tag it "homework."

Comment: Those -1 should be `string::npos`.

Comment: Hello kelly, welcome to stack overflow!  Here's a tip when asking for help.  Usually, writing "it doesn't work" is not very informative.  It could mean a variety of things (doesn't compile, crashes, doesn't produce proper outputs).  Describing your problem precisely helps us help you.

Comment: Hi K-ballo, I had " while (pos2 != str1.npos)", but then when I used F10 to step through the program, it was showing pos2 as equal to -1, not npos, so I updated my code to -1. I just tried changing it back to str1.npos, and it still isn't working.

Comment: @kelly: regarding `npos`, `npos` is an alias for a value (like any name). Debuggers generally show values, but it makes the code more readable to use those named aliases rather than *magic* values :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say it doesn't work, but you don't say how.  I can see two immediate
prblems: the first is that you return immediatly when you find the first
word with an even length, so you obviously won't break any following
words; and the second is that if you do want to continue, the `insert`
will have changed the values of any position after it.

(FWIW: I'd probably break the entire string down into words first,
putting them in an `std::vector<std::string>`, then iterate on that,
inserting the extra space where needed, then reassemble them.  It's
probably a bit slower than the approach you're using, but it's a lot
cleaner and easier to follow.)

Answer (score 0):

You have a return in your while-loop, so after the first insertion, it will exit the function.

Comment: Hi John, I am calling the breakString() function in a while loop from my main program which executes until my checkForEvenSubsets() returns "false", so I think the "return" is okay here. I tried deleting it from the code, but I am still getting the same error (which is an infinite loop in my main function).

Answer (score 0):

```
void breakString(string &str1){
    string::size_type pos1 = 0;
    string::size_type pos2 = str1.find_first_of(" ");

    while (pos2 != string::npos){
        if((pos2 - pos1) % 2 == 0){
            str1.insert(pos1 + (pos2-pos1)/2, 1, ' ');
            pos2 += 1;
        }

        pos1 = str1.find_first_not_of(" ", pos2);
        pos2 = str1.find_first_of(" ", pos1);
    }

    if((str1.size() - pos1) % 2 == 0)     
        str1.insert(pos1 + (str1.size() - pos1)/2, 1, ' ');

    return;
}
```